# Bootstrap and CSS Layering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a simple HTML file with bootstrap and I can't seem to reach a simple layering effect for some reason.

Desired result:
[image]
The layers are marked by z-index as follows:
1. body
2. half transparent orange bar
3. content: text, logo, image

Code I am using:

```css
.container :first-child {
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
#orange_bar {
 height: 60px;
 left: 0;
    right: 0;
 background-color: #F8EBD2;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}
#content {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
}
#logo {
 margin-top: 30px;
 width: 100px;
}
#banner {
 width: 533px;
}
.inline {
 display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
 color: #d86213;
}
.list-inline {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40px 10px 0 0;
}
.list-inline li {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="orange_bar"></div>
   <div id="content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/w/h/white-tiger-love.jpg?1" id="logo" class="inline pull-right" alt="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PEbFLhe.png" id="banner" class="inline pull-right" alt="banner">
  <nav>
  <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
   <li><a href="">nav1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">nav2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   </header>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set your position property to **property: absolute** for all the different layers.
Next you need to get set your **z-index** values in much *higher numbers* to be more effective over various browsers.  Try the following CSS modifications

```
.container :first-child {
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
z-index: -100;}

#orange_bar {
height: 60px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #F8EBD2;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;}

#content {
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;}
```

This should help the dependencies of the **z-index** take effect even though the stacking of your divs are placed inside each other.  This should take care of it.  Just make sure you're using larger integers for your z-indexes and use **position:absolute** for this case.

Comment: Well, since i'm using Bootstrap, the entire layout is messed up. I have created a JSFiddle for you to see. http://jsfiddle.net/0b7k768k/

Anyways, I have fixed it just by making `z-index` numbers larger.

Comment: Also, could you explain why I need to set larger `z-index` numbers? doesn't each number represent a layer?

Comment: yes, the z-indexes do just represent layers.  In my experience, setting them further apart works best between different browser types.  Sometimes setting them 1 or 2 numbers apart doesn't have a strong enough priority to take effect.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I was expecting a more thorough answer to understand how this thing works but I guess that as long as I get the desired result it doesn't really matter. Thanks David!