# Why does z-index needs large numbers?

Tags: css

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937946/bootstrap-and-css-layering/33944534#33944534), it seems that I had to use `z-index` with large numbers to get the desired result while in w3schools or any other website I've seen uses smaller numbers as each step defines a new layer as you can see [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index). Or here:
[image]

Any idea why this example works only when the steps are in the hundreds and not single unit steps? http://jsfiddle.net/0b7k768k/2/

Thanks

Comment: Any z-index will overide  default styling. So if you want to have a lot of z-indexes it's best to use higher ones for more important styles.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? maybe illustrate with an example?

Comment: Z-index does not necessarily needs bigger values. It's value should be relatively larger than the other

Comment: @Maverick "It's value should be relatively larger than the other" - Please elaborate on why that is necessary, that is in fact my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `z-index` property can only be seen if it has something to compare with. The value doesn't have to be very large but it should be larger or smaller when compared to the element you want above or below it. The confusion in its use is obvious as it only works if the position of element has set to the `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`. Read more about it http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/#why-does-it-cause-confusion

Comment: So basically you're saying each unit step defines a layer but in order to avoid "unknown" variables (other z-index from different frameworks such as bootstrap) I should use large numbers?

Comment: That may be a way to look at it but avoid using too large number as there's a highest value for it.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
#orange_bar {
height: 60px;
background-color: #F8EBD2;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

#content {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

It works perfect even if you give small value to z-index. In this case, the z-index of #content should be relatively large than #orange_bar.

Comment: My previous question was already answered, though I really appreciate you trying to help!! please help me understand why some people keep saying I need to use larger numbers. :)

Comment: The reason they are telling you to use large numbers so that you have multiple options while using Z-index. Eg- if you have 3 elements then smaller values can be used. But in case of multiple elements where every one needs Z-index then using large numbers gives you a variety of options while placing elements. Ofcourse you can still work it out with smaller ones.